# OSX 10.9 auto inherit network group permissions

Tags: macos, active-directory, file-permissions

I'm trying to set up a series of local directories on an OSX 10.9 machine which is connected to a windows domain. I have set the folders to have the correct permissions.

for example the "INTAKE07" directory has read/write permissions for any users in the network group INTAKE07. But whenever a user from this group makes a new subdirectory it only has read/write permissions for the owner and not for that network group.

I believe I the answer might be something to do with umask, but I have no idea.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it with this command in the end:

```
chmod +a "group:DOMAIN_NAME\Intake07 allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /path/to/folder
```